# How to determine mathematically that an expression with one independent variable forms a closed area or not

Tags: functions, plane-curves, closed-graph

Is there any mathematical method {other than sketching the curve  from  given expression (or equation)} to determine whether a given expession (or equation) forms a closed area or not?

For example- equation of circle form a closed area but how to check it  mathematically without sketching  its $x$-$y$  curve ?

Comment: http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~cs577/handouts/space-curves.pdf the first/second page is relevant

Comment: @RyanShesler This relates to explicit parametrization (where you can just check by checking injectivity). From the example of a circle, it seems to me that the questioner talks about implicit parametrizations.

Comment: I don't see that the "equation of a circle" is an "instance" of "an expression with one independent variable."  That phrase, taken from your title, seems more like the notion of a function (of the one independent variable).

Comment: @k.stm I added that note to my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: This is a half-answer, because it is for parametric curves. Some implicit curves can be parameterized, in which case this applies. I am not aware of a method for determining if a curve is closed given an implicit equation.

Basically, say you have some $t$ that traces out the curve via $(x(t), y(t))$, and say $t$ starts at $0$. If this is a closed curve in the sense you and I are thinking, then after a certain point it will just trace over the original shape. Let's say it returns to its starting point at $\alpha$ for some real number. Then it is closed if $(x(t), y(t)) = (x(u),y(u))$ if and only if $t = u + k\alpha$ for some integer $k$.

Let's use a circle as an example. We have a circle with radius $1$ is traced by the parametric equation with $t$ starting at $0$
$$(\cos(t), \sin(t))$$
Now we have that $t = 2\pi$ is the first time that we have a repeat point, namely,
$$(\cos(2\pi), \sin(2\pi)) = (\cos(0), \sin(0))$$
Actually, for every $t$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, we have
$$(\cos(t+2\pi), \sin(t+2\pi)) = (\cos(t), \sin(t))$$
This applies for any multiple of $2\pi$, as it just keeps tracing over the original circle. Therefore, we say that this equation is closed because for $t = u + k*2\pi$, where $k$ is an integer,
$$(\cos(t), \sin(t)) = (\cos(u), \sin(u))$$
By requiring that there is no repeating point without tracing over the whole shape again, we have a simple closed curve (think of this like no loops where the curve intersects itself), which means there is a discernable area enclosed by the curve.